# Dynamic Linq 'contains' clause without using placeholder

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-core-mvc, dynamic-linq

The syntax given for contains clause is

```
ids = new int[] {1,2,3,4};
dataContext.Table.Where("@0.Contains(id)", ids);
```

But what I want is

```
dataContext.Table.Where("{1,2,3,4}.Contains(id)"); //getting exception here
```

> [ERROR] Expression expected (at index 0)

I need this because the where clause my or may not use the contains method. it depends on how user acts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I got the answer for this after tinkering for sometime. So posting the answer here.

```
 dataContext.Table.Where("new Int[]{1,2,3,4}.Contains(id)");
```

You can use whatever datatype you need. I use reflection to find datatype and use that accordingly.

Comment: this is wrong answer,How To Execute query , This Query Where cause has some invalid arguments

Comment: its dynamic linq dude

Answer (score 0):

try code:

```
int[] ids= {1,2,3,4};

dataContext.Table.Where(c=>c.ids.Contains(t.id)).ToList();
```

Or

```
var result= (from p in dataContext.Table.AsEnumerable()
                      join q in ids on p.id equals q
                        select p).Distinct() .ToList();
```

Comment: But why are you using Dynamic LINQ when you don't need to?

Comment: i do need to use it.Every column and every filter condition is determined at runtime